# What is the "official" way to create/configure a service under Windows?

Tags: windows, service

When I use `sc  create  "myService"  binpath= “C:\Program Files\myService\myService.exe"` I have no way to configure some aspects of the service. In particular the `Recovery` tab seen in `services.msc` (action on first failure, action on second failure, restart service after, etc).

I currently manually modify these parameters, but is there a better method?
A PowerShell command or so? What I found about PowerShell do not allow much better than `sc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to configure the Recovery options for a service that you create using the `sc` command, you can use the `failure` option to set them.

```
sc failure
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc742019(v%3Dws.11)

The `New-Service` PowerShell cmdlet also works.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-service?view=powershell-6

Comment: So simple and I overlooked the "failure" sub-command. many thanks. For the powershell part I do not see the equivalent to "failure". Or is it "-WhatIf"?

Comment: From what I can see, there's no option to configure a service's recovery options via PowerShell. Most of the solutions posted online are PowerShell scripts that calls the "sc failure" command, like the example below.

https://evotec.xyz/set-service-recovery-options-powershell/